# Struts 2 Action not getting invoked

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, validation, struts2

For couple of days, I am trying to see as why my action is not getting invoked in this particular form.

My Form is something like below and I have struts URL tags which I am using along with Bootstrap framework:

```
 <s:form action="RegisterUser" cssClass="form-horizontal" id="id-register-form" method="post">
   Couple of Struts 2 UI tags
 </s:form>
```

My Register user action is very simple with just an execute method in it which returns string `"success"`:

```
public class RegisterUser extends ActionSupport {

    public RegisterUser() {
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside execute method test 1!");
          return "success";
    }

}
```

My `struts.xml` for the above looks something like below:

```
 <action name="RegisterUser" class="Mypackage.RegisterUser" method="execute"> 
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/views/usermanagement/register-success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/WEB-INF/views/usermanagement/register-error.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

But whenever I click the submit button of the form,form submission is never triggered. I have client side validation with jquery with jquery validate library and then doing server side with struts validation framework,but I believe issue is not related to validation but more on action mapping side or something related to submit button.Below is my submit button,

```
<s:submit type="button" cssClass="btn btn-primary" value="Create Account" cssStyle="float:left;">Create Account</s:submit>
```

Appreciate if someone can take a look and give me some insights. I am on Glassfish v4 and using Netbeans IDE and my Struts 2 is 2.3.15.3 on win 8.1

Here is my JS code for client side validation with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#id-register-form").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "Email") {
                error.appendTo('#error-Email');
            }
            else if (element.attr("name") == "Password") {
                error.appendTo('#error-Password');
            }
            else if (element.attr("name") == "ConfirmPassword") {
                error.appendTo('#error-ConfirmPassword');
            }
            else if (element.attr("name") == "AgreetoPolicy") {
                error.appendTo('#error-Agree');
            }

        },
        rules: {
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            Password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            ConfirmPassword: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                equalTo: "#Password"
            },
            AgreetoPolicy: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            Email: "<small>Please enter a valid email address</small>",
            Password: {
                required: "<small>Please provide a password</small>",
                minlength: "<small>Your password must be at least 8 characters long</small>"
            },
            ConfirmPassword: {
                required: "<small>Please provide a password</small>",
                minlength: "<small>Your password must be at least 5 characters long</small>",
                equalTo: "<small>Please enter the same password as above</small>"
            },
            AgreetoPolicy: "<strong><small>Please accept our policy</small></strong>"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is your submit button inside your form ?

Comment: any error from javascript console ?

Comment: No its clean no error or warnings in console.

Comment: No errors, and no submit ? What do you see in Firebug NET Panel, if using Firefox, or in the same tool in another browser ? Any network traffic ?

Comment: no network traffic as well. I check in chrome developer tool bar.No network traffic on submit click.

Comment: @KiranBadi Can you trigger the action in your browser?

Comment: For post how do I trigger it manually, you want me to append values to query string and convert the form submission to get and see ..

Comment: Yup when I trigger it it works and action is called successfully.Not sure as whats issue with form then?

Comment: The problem is with javascript code which you didn't post.

Comment: I posted the js code which does client side validation.

Comment: After removing the jquery validation it works,I am submit the form but now how to do client side validatation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this code where messages

```
Email:  {
          required: "<small>Please enter a valid email address</small>",
          email: "Email addresses are of the form user@host."
        }
```

Comment: Hah got it but issue is that with jquery validate its not submitting the form.Any suggestion as how to make it work ?

Comment: Yes already done.but still same issue.Cannot have jquery validate with struts 2 ui tag.Without jquery validate ,action is getting called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yup issue is resolved now.It was my broken Jquery validation code that was responsible for not submitting the form...Thanks Roman and Andrea for your help and assistance.Appreciate it.